# HDF5 - why do some tools store scalar attributes as arrays of size 1?

Tags: hdf5, h5py

`hdfview` (v2.9) for instance stores a strings and scalar values in general like in this example (these are mapped to arrays of size 1 in `h5py` / `numpy`):

```
ATTRIBUTE "title" {
   DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
      STRSIZE 256;
      STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
      CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
      CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
   }
   DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( 1 ) }
   DATA {
   (0): "Storm 4231"
   }
}
```

The same attribute created via `h5py` is stored as follows, which seems much more logical:

```
ATTRIBUTE "title" {
   DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
      STRSIZE 10;
      STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLPAD;
      CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
      CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
   }
   DATASPACE  SCALAR
   DATA {
   (0): "Storm 4231"
   }
}
```